# How to display bunch of images without giving the local resource names in the code?

Tags: blackberry

Hi I am working on a application where I need to display bunch of images for some conditions. Is there any simpler way to get all images without mentioning the resource names as in Android platform like

```
 int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable",
            getPackageName());
```

Please anybody help me in this regard.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want to hard code image names.
So you can use ResourceBundle.

```
static ResourceBundle _resources=ResourceBundle.getBundle(MyAppResourcesResource.BUNDLE_ID, MyAppResourcesResource.BUNDLE_NAME);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(_resources.getString(MyAppResourcesResource.IMAGE_NAME));
```

For details of ResourceBundle read this article.

[Localizing an application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Localizing-an-application/ta-p/442726)